# How do I handle referenced table Ids in real code

Tags: php, sql, database, api

I have project to work out a API that is steadily growing. its my first PHP thing and it will be used in a Angular based webpage I work on as well.

Currently I try to lay down the entities of my data structure and build an API with SlimPHP and Doctrine. So much for the background.

My problem is haunting me through out many of my Many-to-Many connections but I think its best to explain it on a single example.

I have a User Table. It takes usual data for users and stuff. Nothing special here. Users can have roles. Examples: base users, admins, whatever. These "types" are layed out in a RoleType table. They have an Id, a "name" and a description. I also have Games in their own table. Also with names, Id, and other stuff.

Now i wanna give a user a role specific to a game. For that i created a "role" table. This one is build upon foreign keys from user, game and roleType only taking the respective ids and working as a relation table.

[image: ERM of the example]

all of that is working great. I set my API up to give a user with its roles, I can get all roles of a user and so on.

Now comes the hard stuff: I wanna assign one of the roles (base user) to every user on creation on the backend for every game. For that i expanded the creation method to iterate through all created games on user creation and create a "role" relation in the role table for every game. BUT: For that to work i had to query my roleTypes table for the id of the "base user" role.

Here is a code example. Especially the first line is important. Its mostly Doctrince specific syntax but in the first line I query for "baseUser" which is the exact spelling of the standard role.

```
$type = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('App\Entity\RoleType')->findOneByTitle("baseUser");
    $games = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('App\Entity\Game')->findAll();

    foreach ($games as $game) {
        $role = new RoleEntity();
        $user->__get("roles")->add($role);
        $role->__set("user", $user);
        $role->__set("game", $game);
        $role->__set("type", $type);
        $this->getEntityManager()->persist($role);
    }
    return $user;
```

My Question is now: Is that the right way to do it? I learned in university and on other occasions that string matches should be avoided. If anyone besides me will change that code or write their own (quite possible) I would have to make sure that they know for every "role check" the right spelling for that role and make that spelling a fixed thing.

Another way to do it would be to remember the Id of that role and check against that one on every occassion. Leaving me with the problem "what if the id changes in the future".

It seems to me that the code and the actualm content of the database should not interfer and rely on each other but i cant think of any way I could make my code assign a specific role or check for a role without giving it the string or its id.

Am I wrong or is that the "right" way to do what I try to achieve?

Comment: That's a lot of text with no examples there.   You'll stand a better chance of getting an answer if you provide at least a basic table structure for what you've worked out, and even better an entity-relationship diagram

Comment: thx for that advice. I added some stuff to hopefully make it more appealing :)

Comment: Things like that are usually handle by configuration files. You specify for instance a configuration array `["defaultRoleType" => "baseUser"]`. Like that you depend on the configuration and no more on the spelling of `baseUser`. Confg files usually depends on the environment/installation instance so I think it may be fine in your case.

Comment: So you mean, I define some sort of "global" variable array that contains the spelling of the database file and matches them to a variable name that can be used throughout the whole code?